# Cesium 3DEarth : make Earth rotate

Tags: cesiumjs

I've developed a SW, using `Cesium.js`. The SW shows the satellites, which rotate around the Earth in the inertial reference frame.

The problem is, to make the model more realistic, I have to make the Earth rotate. The rotation should comply with the speed of the scene (as I can accelerate it). How to do that?

It looks like, it's not similar to the rotation of the camera.

Comment: @emackey No. That question was about Inertial system. Your answer helped, I changed the configuration to INERTIAL. This question is about the Earth rotation.

Comment: @emackey And I don't use CZML file

Comment: Did you try the `icrf` code sample from midway through my answer?  Does that produce the Earth rotation you're looking for, or is there some other kind of rotation needed?